# Oracle query, union statement slower than individual statements

Tags: oracle11g, sqlperformance

Each individual query takes only a couple of seconds to compute. Combining those queries with UNION and the database doesn't answer at all (or at least, not within an hour). Queries look like this:

```
select 111 old_id, 'old_state' old_state, t_id new_id, state new_state from tableA where t_id in (select t_fk from tableB where t_id in (select distinct t_parent_id from tableC where t_parent_id is not null and t_num=444))
union
select 222 old_id, 'old_state' old_state, t_id new_id, state new_state from tableA where t_id in (select t_fk from tableB where t_ih in (select distinct t_parent_id from tableC where t_parent_id is not null and t_num=555))
```

Query looks a bit odd, because I have to generate it from an Excel sheet. Still, UNION shouldn't decrease performance dramatically, so where does this go wrong?

Interestingly, the problem doesn't occure if I leave out the most outer select statement, like this:

```
select t_fk from tableB where t_id in (select distinct t_parent_id from tableC where t_parent_id is not null and t_num=444)
union
(select t_fk from tableB where t_id in (select distinct t_parent_id from tableC where t_parent_id is not null and t_num=555))
```

Execution plans (first, individual query, then with UNION)

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
Plan hash value: 897971467
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name                          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                               |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                     |                               |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                    |                               |
|   3 |    VIEW                           | redacted                      |
|   4 |     HASH UNIQUE                   |                               |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                 |                               |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                |                               |
|   7 |        VIEW                       | redacted                      |
|   8 |         HASH UNIQUE               |                               |
|   9 |          TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| redacted                 |
|  10 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | redacted |
|  11 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | redacted      |
|  12 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | redacted         |
|  13 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | redacted              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
Plan hash value: 3071639821
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                    |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL                              |                    |
|   2 |   FILTER                                |                    |
|   3 |    INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN         | redacted |
|   4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | redacted    |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL FIRST ROWS| redacted      |
|   6 |   FILTER                                |                    |
|   7 |    INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN         | redacted |
|   8 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | redacted    |
|   9 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL FIRST ROWS| redacted      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do the individual queries take a few seconds to fetch all results, or just to return *something* (e.g. first 50 rows by default in SQL Developer with run command)? Union (without 'all') eliminates duplicates, so all data has to be retrieved, sorted and compared internally before anything can be returned. Look at the execution plans to see what is happening. You probably do want `union all` here, but it would maybe still be faster with a single statement that combines the two `t_num` values.

Comment: Individual queries return exactly one row each. I've already tried Union all, doesn't change the performance.

Comment: OK, so what do the execution plans for the individual queries and the union show?

Comment: I added the execution plans. But I don't really know what they are telling me, despite that they are obviously different.

Comment: I read up a bit on the meaning of the items of these execution plans. Seems to me, that filtering implies sort and that adds quit a lot of performance loss. Still not sure how to test this / get rid of FILTER.

Answer (score 0):

I rerun the execution plans with the cost displayed. I noticed that in the UNION statement the first/outer select generated costs of about 82G. I couldn't tell why this happened, the execution plan below that was quit similar in terms of cost with the individual statements.

Anyway, I've rewritten the query to make the first and second select one query via join, that resolved the performance issue.